# Excel VBA Setting Cell Colour based on range of individual cells

Tags: vba, excel, range

After much messing about and trying to sort this out I am at a loss. I have a C# interop that returns a CSV list of cell addresses. This part works without a problem. I have a method that sets the cell colour of these to red:

```
Worksheets(Worksheet).range(errorCells).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 80, 83)
```

errorCells is a string that contains data such as

```
"O148,O389,O396,O397,O398,O399,O400,O401,O402,O403,O404,O405,O406,O407,O408,O409,O410"
```

My problem is when the string of errorCells is large (around 56 elements) Excel throws:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

The csv list is passed into the method correctly. This has essentially been changed to aid in performance as doing one cell at a time was more than a bit inefficient.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: So your method works if errorCells only contains 1 item? and also any number below 56?

Comment: It works if there are around 30 entities in the csv line. Thing is where I get confused and I didn't think there would be a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try a different approach. Assuming that those 4 digit error cell numbers somehow correspond to [Row, Column] cell referencing you could try this:

```
Dim varSplit As Variant 
varSplit = Split(errorCells, ",") 'Read into an array each value to access
```

Then loop over the varSplit object using For Each loop and:

1. Split up each string into row and column parts
2. Access your Range(s) that need to be coloured by using:

   ```
   Cells(Row,Column).Interior.Color  = RGB(216, 80, 83)
   ```

Comment: Is this that quick as I'd originally passed back an array and looped over this setting the range for each cell, using the A34 reference?

Comment: Is performance really an issue here? You mentioned that you're doing this for 56 cells, is that representative?

Comment: This is for one column set there are upwards of 12 column sets and then the entire sheet, which can be thousands of rows. Its an inherited project so having to work with what I've got. This is really a nicety so will probably just go to your suggestion to get it working.

Comment: In my experience, working with modern machines, writing to cells or modifying them in large quantities only becomes a performance issue to the point that it is noticeable when you're dealing with tens of thousands of rows at least. When this becomes an issue I follow the advice given in this [blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices.aspx) . If you're talking about programmatically changing the colour of an entire sheet you can use ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(216, 80, 83)